# How to detect Facebook in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, browser, in-app

Have you had any experience in Facebook in-app browser detection?
What's the core difference in user agent?

I don't want to know if it is a only mobile/ios/chrome. I need to know whether user agent is specific from *Facebook in-app browser*

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can check for FBAN / FBAV in the user agent.

Check this link:
[Facebook user agent](http://mpulp.mobi/2012/01/funky-user-agent-on-facebook-iphone-app/)

Comment: What does ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1 and ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1 mean? Force out user to use web browser instead of in-apps browser?

Comment: @RobbNesp `var us = navigator.userAgent` gives you a string value.
`.indexOf()` checks for the position of a sub-string in a string.  If it is not found a value of -1 is returned.
It is simply checking if it is the Facebook browser, by checking if the browser's user agent contains either of the given sub strings.

Comment: Thanks! Sharing snippet for Instagram also: `(ua.indexOf('Instagram') > -1)`

Comment: I added the snippet to the answer, thanks @jeff_drumgod

Comment: Can you explain the `|| window.opera` bit? I don't think it would cast to the user agent string.

Comment: Thanks a zillion.

Comment: Does it work for both Facebook apps on Android and iOS devices?

Answer (score 43):

To complete worker11811's answer on using the user agent, here's a code snippet to make it work:

```
function isFacebookApp() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-inapp and check if inapp.isInApp() is true

Comment: This is really helpful and verymuch effective