# Facebook in-app browser cuts off top of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, facebook

When clicking a website link from within the Facebook iOS app, the page loads fine (within the in-app browser). But then when you scroll down and then back up, the top is cut off. This is a problem for website with a nav bar at the top, like amazon.com. Is there a workaround for this? One that does not involve the user having to disable the in-app browser. This is aweful when you realize you've spent money sending people to a website they cannot use.

Update: This seems to be an issue with a slightly older version of the Facebook App for iOS. In the newer version of the FB App, this is not a problem.

Even still, I'd like to know if anyone has experienced this and if so, is there an HTML, javascript or jquery solution to the problem. I know I can detect the FB browser, maybe even the version of the in-app browser. But still, what to do then.

I think I am going to try using frames. I guess I could pad the top and bottom.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWqUS.jpg)

Comment: Hi Kelly, I am afraid this is not the type of question which are usually answered here. In the situation you're describing the question would be written by developer of the in-app browser describing what code he has used and the problem his/her users are facing (you). Then user of this website can help solve the programmer problem. As a user I would suggest to voice your concern to the support team of the application you're using. I am sorry as it is probably not helping you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I should have been more clear. The websites I have written are not working properly within the Facebook in-app browser. As it seems, the updated version of the Facebook app has been fixed. But there are still older version floating around that exhibit this problem. My questions was, from an html/java/jquery stand point. Is there a web page workaround for this pretty big problem.

Comment: In that case I would suggest having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In your case, it would mean writing a small html/java/jquery which exhibits the issue with the old in-app browser.

Comment: I don't know much about the technologies involved in your question, but it could be that this previous question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569518/how-to-detect-facebook-in-app-browser could help you figure out if your user is using the old version of the in-app browser.