# How to detect Skype in-app browser via jquery?

Tags: jquery, browser, skype, in-app

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348687/248616), we have a way to detect if the client web browser is Facebook app browser.

I want to detect Skype app browser too. How can we do that?

Comment: Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype

Comment: That is to tell if Skype intalled; my OP asking way to tell, from jQuery, if web client is in-app Skype web browser.