# Android Firebase Dynamic links not working in Facebook messenger properly

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, facebook-messenger, firebase-dynamic-links

I integrated my application with dynamic links from firebase successfully. But when I share a short link with `SocialMetaTagParameters` and click on the link in messenger it opens the browser and it should redirected to my application, but it is entering in infinite loop in the browser.

I found similar issue created in google groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/nOOcOwmxl58

**This is my code to create short link:**

```
Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
    .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
    .setDynamicLinkDomain(mContext.getString(R.string.firebaseAppCode))
    // Set parameters
    .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
    .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.xxxx.xxxx").build())
    .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
        new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .build()
    )

    .buildShortDynamicLink()
    .addOnCompleteListener((Activity) mContext, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Short link created
                Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();

                ShareApp(mContext, shortLink.toString());
            } else {
                Utils.ShowToast(mContext, "Sharing failed, Try again");
            }
        }
    });
```

**This is my code to share the short dynamic link:**

```
public static void ShareApp(Context mContext,String link) {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,link);
    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share..."));
}
```

This is code in manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".UI.Home.Consultants.ViewConsultantProfileActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="Profile"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="consultrustconsultant"
            android:scheme="http"/>
        <data
            android:host="consultrustconsultant"
            android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note:

if I removed SocialMetaTagParameters, the link is working properly and when click on the link its redirected to my application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase dynamic links is not launching my app in specific situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217810/firebase-dynamic-links-is-not-launching-my-app-in-specific-situation)

Comment: No its not duplicated.

Comment: I think the best bet here is to file a ticket with the support team and include the actual deep link that doesn't work - it'll be easier to debug. One other trick is to use the debugging (append &d=1 to the long link) to see if there are any warnings in there! https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @MinaFared found a solution for this ?

Comment: @Mr.G sorry i didn't find yet. its a bug from messenger itself

Comment: did u try to constructor the URL manually ? and this works if i share a link through iOS

Comment: the strange behavior is when you copy the link to messenger manually it will work, but it will not work if it's sent using share intent.