# Is there an easy way to detect if a website user is browsing with the facebook in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook, browser

I'm looking for a very simple piece of code that will check if a website user is browsing with the facebook in-app browser. I was able to produce a very simple piece of code to check for safari users. I'm hoping I can find something just as clean and simple for the facebook in-app browser.

Kind of like this:

### JS

```
var isSafari = window.safari !== undefined;

function checkbrowser() {
    if (isSafari) {
        alert('safari incompatibility warning');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `navigator.appName` or look at the request headers.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus `navigator.appName` cannot be used for this. The Facebook app returns "Netscape". User agent Strings may change over time, but so far I have been using this: `var isFbInAppBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FBAV') > -1;` _("FBAV" stands for "FaceBook App Version")_

Comment: Yea, that's kind of why I was asking. Every browser I checked returned navigator.appName as "Netscape".

I'll try this var check out right now.

Comment: @blex That totally did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: so what is the answer here?  I need to trigger a Jquery Mobile pop up if the user enters from the facebook browser. Facebook doesn't allow any geolocation so i need to make a special function for this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Facebook in-app browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569518/how-to-detect-facebook-in-app-browser)