# Can't open camera in Android Facebook app inbox browser by using html input tag

Tags: html

I try to write a website to take a picture and upload image.
In HTML5 I use input tag such as:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`

to open camera and it really work in most of browsers,
but it can't open in Android Facebook inbox browser, it would appear open file replace open camera.
Does anyone has faced this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this behavior too. It's possible that the Facebook app restricts this permission.  While I haven't found a solution yet, you can [detect the presence of Facebook's in-app browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569518/how-to-detect-facebook-in-app-browser) and display a notification, telling the user to load your website in a normal browser for best results.

Update 8/7/18: If the Facebook for Android app does not have certain Android permissions enabled (Camera, Location, etc), those same features will not be available in Facebook's in-app browser.