# Detect Facebook Mobile Browser and adapt CSS accordingly

Tags: wordpress, facebook

The font on my Wordpress website is rendering at a larger size on the Facebook Mobile Browser - not significantly - but enough that it changes the whole look of the website.

I've tried using px, em and rem for the font sizing but still getting the same result - also tried reducing the size of the font in Wordpress. This didn't work as in order to get the font to display at the size I need on the Facebook Mobile Browser - its elegible on every other browser.

Is there any way to detect the Facebook Mobile Browser and reduce the font size accordingly with CSS?

Comment: I doubt there’s any documented CSS hacks or something like that. Your best bet is probably to detect it by its User-Agent, and then add a class to the html or body element based on that, so that you can use that to format stuff differently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569518/how-to-detect-facebook-in-app-browser

Comment: Thank you I'll try that.