# JS - Mobile - Open Safari from any browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, https, safari

Since Apple allow use of camera in Safari (Mobile), we can do a lot things, but sharing them is hard. You cannot open a website in Safari from another browser directly (Chrome, FacebookBrowser, MessengerBrowser, SkypeBrowser...).

Safari has 4 URL Schemes:

`(HTTP) — http://websiteurl`

`(HTTPS) — https://websiteurl`

`x-web-search://` - Google search in Safari

`(FTP) — ftp://locationtofileonftpserver`

If you use `<a href="https://somewebsite"></a>`
 or `window.open("http://somewebsite")`. It always uses the current browser to open URL.

`x-web-search://?[query]` - It will open Safari but using Google and search something in query

Hence, only `ftp` remains. If you want to open website (HTTPS) in Safari, you will need a bridge html file in your ftp server and open it as:

`ftp://your_ip_address/bridge.html` Now, the only thing "bridge.html" does is

```
<script>
    window.open("https://your_url", "_self");
</script>
```

And Safari will open your website from any browser

You can add params URL to your `ftp` link (`ftp://your_ip_address/bridge.html?url=https://someURL`)
 Catch it in bridge.html before `window.open`

Hope it helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. Should the ftp where the bridge file is stored be open (anonymous authentication)? I am trying the solution proposed but on safari I get "unknown error" when the trying opening the ftp://000.000.000.000/bridge.html

Comment: Sorry I edited to make clearly. it should ```ftp://your_ip/bridge.html```

But I think this solution only work in webapp browser. I had tested in chrome and It didn't work anymore. But work fine in facebook browser any some another webapp browser. 

You may try my latest project has use this trick https://unboxnote10.com/ (you should open url in facebook app)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I get an `unknown error` in mobile and desktop Safari.