# How can I reach a HTML file over FTP stored on Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, ftp, firebase-hosting

How can I reach a HTML file over FTP stored on Firebase hosting. i.e. on how can I call `ftp://your_ip_address/bridge.html` if `bridge.html` is hosted with Firebase?

**Why do I want to do this?**

So I have a website running WebRTC for camera access. I've been getting some complaints from users about how WebRTC is not available in apps (i.e. UIWebView / WKWebView don't support WebRTC). The best solution I can think of is to make a pop up that takes users to Safari in this instance. [Detecting this scenario is quite straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript). The issue is really opening Safari. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025910/js-mobile-open-safari-from-any-browser) on how to do this, however, it requires that I make an FTP request to a server. I'm using Firebase for hosting so I don't really know how to access the level of filesystems. Is there another way to set this up or something I can do on Firebase to get to reach a HTML file over FTP from Safari URL schemes? If not then is the only alternative for me to get a separate FTP server and store the file there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Hosting does not implement an FTP server, so you can not interact with it with FTP client commands. If you must use FTP to read from/write to your hosting provider, you may want to look at other services that *do* support that requirement.