# How to open Safari browser from any other browser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari, webbrowser-control

I'm working on the core Php(PHP + bootstrap + jquery) website and I want to open the safari browser from any browser with a special URL.
IOS users are using many kinds of web browsers but my site is working on the only safari with ios users.
So when IOS users call a special URL, the safari browser should open with this URL.
I think I may use javascript functions.
Please let me know if you have any good solutions.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

JavaScript does not have that kind of access to your system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mr.Cerbrus.
I saw this url
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025910/js-mobile-open-safari-from-any-browser)
But it's not working on my chrome.
It seems to run on firefox, but it's actually not what I wanna.
So you think there is no solution?

Comment: Passing it through an `ftp://`? That reads like a rather dubious hack... I'm not surprised it doesn't work. As I said, this is not something you have control over.

Comment: And if users want to open chrome, not safari, is it possible?

Comment: All you can do is just place an url in your website. The user's device will then choose what to do with it.

Comment: This [link](https://www.itworld.com/article/3008858/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html) says that we can open a special browser on safari.
But I wanna from any browser to just safari, not from safari to special browser.