# PWA on iOS won't let me dowload image from my app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I got some serious trouble with PWA (react-creat-app) in iOS about images. I would like to let my users download image that they create from my app. All the creating process for image work very well (canvas>base64>dataUrl>new Image()>src...etc...), and it display perfectly, but it's impossible to download it inside my PWA in iOS (all other platform work well)

The weird thing is when I went to my app on Safari iOS, long press to the image let appear the context-menu (share, add to galery...) perfect, but when I launch my PWA, the long press on image don't show the context-menu and select the image as it was a text ?! :s

I thought it was because the image.src was a base64, so I tried with classic image (jpg, png) and it's the same, long press launch context-menu in safari but not in PWA. And it the same for all the PWA's image.

It react like if his css style was `user-select: text;` or `user-select: auto;`

So for now I decide to force downloading the image with an `<a src=[base64] download>` but it open a page not very user friendly [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU8Ze.jpg) !

I'm sure there are a solution to this, or it's maybe an another iOS bug... After 48h testing to fix it, I still blocked on this issue, someone can help me ?

**EDIT**

I've also try to change or remove css `-webkit-touch-callout` but nothing change

**EDIT 2**

Apparently, for ALL PWA in iOS there're the same problem...

**EDIT 3**

I tried 3 another way :

1. create direct link to the image (exemple/url.png) and call it in new tab with window.open() but we still inside the webview not inside 'classic' Safari so the context menu is not working
2. create an iframe that display the image but still same, no context menu
3. create ftp server, but it's also not working because FTP protocol != HTTP protocol. HTTP read and display file in navigator, but FTP protocol just 'serve' it as file, no matter the file extension, it just give you the right to dowload it ([more detail about the tried process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025910/js-mobile-open-safari-from-any-browser)), so the bridge.html page is never read by safari

Why iOS haven't URL scheme for Safari ?!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Dealing with the same issue right now.

Comment: I’d be very interested to know if you or @Tomjr260 figured this out? Same problem here.